# How i can get last value of state? without subscribing (rxJs)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

i have this on facade

```
chatMessagesState$ = this.store.pipe(select(ChatMessageSelectors.getChatMessagesState));
```

this on selector

```
export const getChatMessagesState = createSelector(
  getChatMessages,
  (payload: ChatMessagesState) => payload
);
```

and this on component

```
   this.chatMessagesSub = this.chatMessagesFacade.chatMessagesState$.subscribe(state => {
        if (state.messages) {
        // do something
        }
  });
```

how i can take state, without subscribing?

Comment: I saw that there is some kind of behaviorSubject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 constructor(private storeState: State<YourState>)

 const state = this.storeState.value['your-state'];
```

If you need to take the value just 1 time

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert the `Observable` to a `Promise` and use `async-await`:

```
async getStateValue(){
    const state=await this.chatMessagesFacade.chatMessagesState$.toPromise();
    return state;
  }
```

**Note:** This method defeats the purpose of Observables because you won't be able to listen to changes emitted. Promise will either resolve/reject only once.

Comment: ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state: null
__zone_symbol__value: []
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)
Symbol(Symbol.species): (...)
__proto__: Object

Comment: does not work  :(